# Closure not storing local variables

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to run asynchronous tests in a synchronous order.
That is, each test needs to load files and is thus not synchronous by definition - instead, I want to wait for each test to load its files, run code, and only then go to the next test and load its files, etc.

The problem - very oddly, I get a closure that does not properly keep the values of the local variables immediately outside of it.

This snippet is a part of a larger library, so I can't quite give a self-sufficient example that you can run, however the logic here is pretty straightforward.

```
let viewer = ...;
let tests = [...]; // Let's say the length is 3

function runTestSync(callback, index) {
    console.log("FIRST", index)

    if (index >= tests.length) {
        callback(index, true);
    } else {
        let entry = tests[index];

        // Results in files being loaded
        entry[1](viewer);

        // Add an event listener to the "viewer" object, which will eventually call the callback when all files finished loading
        viewer.addEventListener("loadend", function listener() {
            if (viewer.resourcesLoading === 0) {
                console.log("SECOND", index);

                viewer.removeEventListener(listener);

                callback(index, false);
            }
        });
    }
}

function myIter(index, done) {
    if (!done) {
        runTestSync(myIter, index + 1);
    }
}

runTestSync(myIter, 0);
```

This is the simplest synchronous loop that uses asynchronous server fetches.
I think you can agree that eventually these lines should be printed:

```
FIRST 0
SECOND 0
FIRST 1
SECOND 1
FIRST 2
SECOND 2
```

What happens instead?

```
FIRST 0
SECOND 0
FIRST 1
SECOND 0
FIRST 1
SECOND 0
FIRST 1
...
```

And I get an infinite loop.
Why is the second access to `index` always equal to 0? This is clearly breaking the way closures are supposed to work.

Comment: Your code adds event handlers over and over again to the same object. It's kind-of hard to tell what's going on without seeing the code for what that `viewer` thing is.

Comment: You should delete the first question you posted and remove the link to it from this question.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I can delete questions. The event handler removes itself, so there's only ever one at a time. The viewer object is quite large, but it's actually not related to this code - it doesn't matter how the viewer object loads files or what it does in between - the point is that in the same function, I can access a local variable just fine, but when it's inside a closure in that same function, it suddenly has another value??

Comment: I don't know what `viewer` is, but it looks like it fires the same listener multiple times. Your closures seem fine.

Comment: If the listener was called multiple times, the index would have gotten bigger and bigger, and not stayed at a constant 0. In any case, the listener removes itself in its body, so there is only ever one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the type of the listener to remove at `viewer.removeEventListener(TYPE, listener)`.
Those were 10 hours that I won't get back.